# bugs in Lumia 730 with WhatsApp

Tags: lumia, whatsapp

Sometimes I can't send messages from WhatsApp. When pressing send button it appears like no messages have been sent. There is an another problem that, notifications are not getting untill I manually check for new messages... Can anyone bring a solution for this?

Comment: Check in the battery saver app if what'sapp is allowed to run in backgorund, if not, allow it.Also, chechk if your mobile data is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using Lumia 730 for almost a year and have not come across any such errors.Check your settings for notifications and set it as ON,go to whatsapp->settings->notificatons.

Update or reinstall your whatsapp from windows store.Then it will work fine,good luck!